# Ender 3 homing problem

Tags: creality-ender-3, homing

I got myself a Creality Ender 3 and just finished assembling it and I noticed that the home position is at the right instead of the left. It also is about about 3 mm in front of the right corner.

Anyone could maybe help me to understand what is wrong?

Comment: Welcome to 3DPrinting.SE!

Answer (score 3):

Homing is the process where the machine finds all the limits of the 3 axis (at the endstop switches), to have a common reference point for each axis. From the endstops, firmware defined values exist to give the printer head the offset to the home position, also known as origin (X=0, Y=0). If the origin position is in front of the plate, wrong offsets may be defined, but you can [re-adjust the position](/q/6375).

If the stepper is driving the printer head away from the endstop on a particular axis on homing (in your case the X direction), there might be a few possible problems at hand:

1. The stepper cables are plugged in reversed
2. The wires in the stepper cable are switched
3. The stepper direction is reversed in firmware (this is not very probable for a kit or bought printer)
4. The stepper motor itself is build mirrored (not uncommon mistake for Y stepper motors on the Anet A8)

A quick fix would be to rotate the connector 180° of the cable going into the X stepper, if this works, you can disassemble the cable and properly arrange the stepper wires.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure that the x,y,z and other cords / connectors, were connected to the right areas? TO clarify, the things that connect into the motors.[image: What I was trying to explain. Apologies for the low quality.]

Comment: Hi!

Thanks for your comment!

Yeah, I just checked them. I believe they are all placed correctly...